# Add border all-around and only bottom right cornet radius in swift 2.0

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

I want to add border to my UIView with only bottom left corner radius. I am using following code to achieve required result but is working I am new to swift

```
var layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.bounds = self.myView.bounds

    layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    layer.borderWidth = 2

    callayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.imgView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).CGPath
    self.myView.layer.mask = layer
```

the result

[image]

I am new to swift. How can I have both one corder-radius and border of my UIView?

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.myView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
   self.myView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
   self.myView.layer.cornerRadius =  /*floatvalue*/
```

or you want a circle view

```
 self.myView.layer.cornerRadius =  self.myView.frame.size.width/2
```